# Gnome - input source not working

Tags: x11, gnome, keyboard

I have Elementary OS and there is problem if custom keyboard layout should be added, because currently the [switchboard-plug-keyboard](https://launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-keyboard) uses hardcoded layouts from `data/layouts.txt` and does not scan `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` for new layouts, so you can't add your custom keyboard layout via UI, because it is not shown there.

I manually added my layout to layouts.txt, because the format of this file is simple and easy to understand.

**data/layouts.txt** (the last line i added)

```
#Czech:cz
Czech (UCW layout, accented letters only):ucw
Czech (US Dvorak with CZ UCW support):dvorak-ucw
Czech (qwerty):qwerty
Czech (qwerty, extended Backslash):qwerty_bksl
Czech (with <\|> key):bksl
Czech (programming):kblayout
```

And now i am able to add my layout via UI, **but it does not work when activated.**

**This is what** `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` **returns me**:

```
[('xkb', 'cz'), ('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'cz+kblayout')]
```

In part of **/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml** below, you can see it should be properly configured, but the custom keyboard map not working:

```
<layout>
      <configItem>
        <name>cz</name>

        <shortDescription>cs</shortDescription>
        <description>Czech</description>
        <languageList>
          <iso639Id>cze</iso639Id>
        </languageList>
      </configItem>
      <variantList>
        <variant>
          <configItem>
            <name>bksl</name>
            <description>Czech (with &lt;\|&gt; key)</description>
          </configItem>
        </variant>
        <variant>
          <configItem>
            <name>qwerty</name>
            <description>Czech (qwerty)</description>
          </configItem>
        </variant>
        <variant>
          <configItem>
            <name>qwerty_bksl</name>
            <description>Czech (qwerty, extended Backslash)</description>
          </configItem>
        </variant>
        <variant>
          <configItem>
            <name>ucw</name>
            <description>Czech (UCW layout, accented letters only)</description>
          </configItem>
        </variant>
        <variant>
          <configItem>
            <name>dvorak-ucw</name>
            <description>Czech (US Dvorak with CZ UCW support)</description>
          </configItem>
        </variant>
        <variant>
          <configItem>
            <name>kblayout</name>
            <description>Czech (programming)</description>
          </configItem>
        </variant>
      </variantList>
    </layout>
```

Interesting is that when i use `setxkbmap kblayout` it works and even when i have activated kblayout via UI, in **Keyboard layout chart** i see keyboard map is properly set, but when i press some key, wrong character is given.