# How to get stable International Dvorak with first-level deadkeys in Debian?

Tags: debian, keyboard-layout, x-server, dvorak

There are some unstable/risky ways such as the thread [How to Get A with Dots in Dvorak of Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/a/783984/25388) to get the feature but I cannot run it in many environments. 
Germans need their owns (a/e/u/o with dots) as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/sergeykish/650839), while nordic (Finland, Sweden, Norway, Denmark, ...) people need similar keys  (a/o with dots). 
I think one-level keyboard approach is better than two-level keyboard approach. 
Options

1. To get such a keyboard layout by default in Debian would be great.
2. To get a package in `apt` for such a keyboard would be good.
3. Maybe an other way ...
4. Doing those changes manually like in the first thread is not an option because of the risks in different environments.

OS X International Dvorak has such a feature by default, which can be used as a benchmark, but also the manual approach as done in the first thread answer. 
There is a ticket open in Chromium development for such a feature in the thread [International Dvorak with Deadkeys](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=540815) targeted in Chromebook.

### Testing clearkimura's answer in Debian

1. Output

   ```
   masi@masi:~/Downloads$ sudo cp dvorak_intl /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/dvorak_intl

   masi@masi:~/Downloads$ setxkbmap -verbose dvorak_intl

   masi@masi:~/Downloads$ setxkbmap -I ~/.xkb dvorak_intl -print | xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb - $DISPLAY
   Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
                 Ignoring extra symbols
   Warning:          Key <OUTP> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                 Symbols ignored
   Warning:          Key <KITG> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                 Symbols ignored
   Warning:          Key <KIDN> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                 Symbols ignored
   Warning:          Key <KIUP> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                 Symbols ignored
   Warning:          Key <RO> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                 Symbols ignored
   Warning:          Key <I192> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                 Symbols ignored
   Warning:          Key <I193> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                 Symbols ignored
   Warning:          Key <I194> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                 Symbols ignored
   Warning:          Key <I195> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                 Symbols ignored
   Warning:          Key <I196> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                 Symbols ignored
   Warning:          Key <I255> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                 Symbols ignored
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <AB11> (keycode 97)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <JPCM> (keycode 103)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I120> (keycode 120)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <AE13> (keycode 132)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I149> (keycode 149)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I154> (keycode 154)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I168> (keycode 168)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I178> (keycode 178)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I183> (keycode 183)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I184> (keycode 184)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <FK19> (keycode 197)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <FK24> (keycode 202)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I217> (keycode 217)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I219> (keycode 219)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I221> (keycode 221)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I222> (keycode 222)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I230> (keycode 230)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I247> (keycode 247)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I248> (keycode 248)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I249> (keycode 249)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I250> (keycode 250)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I251> (keycode 251)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I252> (keycode 252)
   Warning:          No symbols defined for <I253> (keycode 253)
   ```
2. Restart
3. Output: the keyboard layout is not active anymore
4. Go to `Region & Language` > choose > search Dvorak > Choose Dvorak with dead keys in Fig. 1
5. Output: the expected keyboard layout now active and selectable in the top bar
6. In Regien & Language, put your primary keyboard layout at the top in Fig. 2 i.e. remove your previous keyboard layouts at the top. This way, you can put *Dvorak international with dead keys* as your primary keyboard which stays there also after restart.

Fig. 1 Region & Language settings after the change, 
Fig. 2 Region & Language settings when *Dvorak international with dead keys* as the primary keyboard layout

[image]
[image]

OS: Debian 8.7
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UB, HP 2002 laptop
Window manager: Gnome 3.14

Comment: I am using us dvorak, with compose key on the `|\ ` (on the querty), the one to the right of the left shift key. This works well for be, however I only type a little of these characters, but also want to type other unicode characters. For example `«compose» o "` gives ö, or `«compose» : )` gives ☺.

Answer (score 3):

This answer shall explain how to install the **Dvorak international extended** keyboard layout found in [this article by Arjen van Kol](http://arjenvankol.com/dvorak.php). The installation and setup were fairly straightforward using XKB.

### Install new layout

Download the layout file `dvorak_intl` from the linked article. Then, copy the file as superuser to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` with the same filename.

```
sudo cp dvorak_intl /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/dvorak_intl
```

No need to further change permission. For curious users, use `stat` command to check the permission. The permission is `644` by default.

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/dvorak_intl 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2989 May 14 17:32 /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/dvorak_intl

$ stat -c '%a %n' /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/dvorak_intl 
644 /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/dvorak_intl
```

### Apply new layout

Before making changes, run `setxkbmap -query` to check the current layout in case we want to revert the changes later. The layout is `us` by default.

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us   <-- current layout
```

Now, run `setxkbmap` command to set the new keyboard layout. The `-verbose` option was added to see the output, which otherwise will show nothing.

```
$ setxkbmap -verbose dvorak_intl
Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard layout
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+dvorak_intl+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
```

User can run again `setxkbmap -query` to verify the changes that have been made and now being shown in the layout column.

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     dvorak_intl   <-- new layout
```

### Test new layout

The changes will be effective immediately; no need to logout or reload X server at all. Open a text editor, then press each keys of four rows on the keyboard to see the output.

First and second level keys (without and with <kbd>Shift</kbd>):

```
`1234567890[]
~!@#$%^&*(){}

´,.pyfgcrl/=\
¨<>PYFGCRL?+|

aoeuidhtns-
AOEUIDHTNS_

;qjkxbmwvz
:QJKXBMWVZ
```

Third and fourth level keys (with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>):

```
 ¡ ♯         
         []{}

´¸…    č     
 «»¶     ¿ 

å°əŭ     ß—
Å  Ŭ      ¯

   ĸ×
```

Not sure if there is any missing keys for third and fourth levels for the keyboard layout `dvorak_intl`, since I am not used to typing at these levels.

### Make layout persistent

The `setxkbmap` command by itself is effective for current session only. However, it is possible to add the following command to startup applications in respective desktop environment.

```
setxkbmap LAYOUTNAME
```

So that the `LAYOUTNAME` will be set up every time the user logs into the system and the desktop session is started. Log out and log in again, then open Terminal and run `setxkbmap -query` to verify that new keyboard layout has been applied for every sessions.

### Configure for non-Debian system

Should the system upgrade overwrites the configuration file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`, then user may relocate the layout configuration file at somewhere else--perhaps Home directory--and remove from system directory to be sure.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.xkb/symbols  
$ cp /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/dvorak_intl ~/.xkb/symbols  
$ sudo rm -i /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/dvorak_intl
```

Then load the layout configuration from there, using the command with `-I` option. It works similarly.

```
$ setxkbmap -I ~/.xkb dvorak_intl
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     dvorak_intl
```

So instead of `setxkbmap LAYOUTNAME`, add `setxkbmap -I ~/.xkb LAYOUTNAME` to startup application in respective desktop environment to load the keyboard configuration for every sessions.

### Discrepancy in Debian

If the command returns "Error loading new keyboard description" message (as described by [this older post on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55933/125388)), then use the following command instead.

```
$ setxkbmap -I ~/.xkb dvorak_intl -print | xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb - $DISPLAY
Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
                  Ignoring extra symbols
Warning:          Key <OUTP> not found in evdev+aliases(qwerty) keycodes
                  Symbols ignored
...
Warning:          No symbols defined for <I253> (keycode 253)
```

Strangely, the last command returns many warning messages that may be related to my foreign keyboard model (Japanese OADG 109A keyboard layout variant). Also, the changes won't be reflected in `setxkbmap -query` but works as expected when typed.

Tested using setxkbmap 1.3.0 in Xubuntu 14.04 (Xfce 4.10), Debian Xfce 8 (Xfce 4.10) and Debian 8.7 Gnome 3.14.

**Disclaimer**: This answer is intended to show how to use XKB to install and set new keyboard layout. The original instruction was found from the [workman/xorg repository](https://github.com/kdeloach/workman/tree/master/xorg), which mentioned both legacy path and current path (for Ubuntu 10.04, GNOME 2.30 back then). However, the instruction has been tested valid for non-GNOME environment i.e. Xfce as well.

The dated instructions provided in `dvorak_intl` file was most likely intended for older releases of GNOME and no longer valid for modern distributions we use today. While legacy path is found at `/etc/X11/xkb/symbols/`, the current path is found at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`.

The <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key refers to the compose key. It is not assigned by default (at least in Xfce) or usually Right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, depending on Linux distribution in use. While I have enabled compose key to demonstrate the third and fourth level keys, the setup for the compose key is *not* shown above.

Comment: This may not provide full answer to what OP want, but at least `dvorak_intl` file has been tested usable and the overwritten config could be avoided by relocating to somewhere else and read using `setxkbmap -I DIR LAYOUTNAME` command.

Comment: It works! After restart, you have to choose the new keyboard manually :) it appeared there! Thank you! Please, see the body for the history.

Comment: I rewarded you the bounty because the change lasts over the restart after the manual change in *Region & Language*. A terminal command for that would also be great. - - Tested on two laptops in Debian 8.7 and Gnome 3.14.

Comment: The command line equivalent to configure "Input Sources" would be `gsettings`, but this may not be used (at least in Debian Xfce) in environment that has low-level configuration system i.e. `xfconf` in Xfce, `dconf` in GNOME.

Comment: Run `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` and see if any layout is listed inside `[]`. If there is any, then you may use `gsettings`, else I'd suggest to use `dconf` in GNOME. Different distribution may configure differently, like [this old post on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226020/125388) (unanswered to this date).

Comment: Yes, it is listed there. I think `gsettings` should work in GNOME.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried a long time ago to make package for a custom keyboard layout. Here the option i could find at that time:

1. Modify original layout (ex: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`)

   Issues:

   - It got overwritten on `xkb-data` update. Package name may differ from distribution to another.
   - Bad idea to create a debian package that overwrites another package file.
2. Add new layout with different name `xy` like in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/482678/26246)

   Issues:

   - Same issues of previous method but with layout declaration file: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` that need to be modified. AFAIK, Xorg server does not support dynamic loading for new layouts.

The above methods relay on XIM (Standard X input method), a legacy system. I would recommend using a modern input method that support plug-ins (modular design) like IBus or SCIM.

I didn't try that but I expect `ibus-table` is the easiest way to go like as explain in [this post](http://www.studymongolian.net/technical/how-to-create-linux-input-method-editor/). The added file could be packaged and installed separately like most IBus engines & layouts, IBus take care to loading them.

**Update:**

Well, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/901356/26246) on AskUbuntu mentions a cleaner way to modify the upstream package. Here are the minimum instructions to rebuild the package

1. Enable the source code for repository
2. Download build dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt build-dep  xkb-data
   ```
3. Download the source

   ```
   mkdir sandbox
   cd sandbox
   apt source xkb-data
   ```
4. Create new quilt patch following [Ubuntu packaging guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/patches-to-packages.html#adding-a-new-patch)

   ```
   cd xkeyboard-config*/
   quilt new username_custom_layout.diff
   quilt add symbols/us
   ```

   Make your needed modification on `symbols/us` then

   ```
   quilt refresh
   ```
5. Build the unsigned source & binary package

   ```
   debuild -us -uc
   ```

Comment: Yeah, basically a debian package just files that should be placed in the correct path. I am interested too in this matter, I will try it and update my answer with my findings.

Comment: Please, let me know if you get anything done. I am interesting how to do it. - - It would be great to maintain international dvorak with deadkeys in Linux.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영, Some one just mention another approach https://askubuntu.com/a/901356/26246 which seems good, creating a modified package from the upstream one.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 I just added the minimum instructiosn to get you on the path, Debian packaging is quite board to make a complete resume here.

Comment: Please, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364644/16920 Almost there. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Example of a custom Dvorak keyboard layout called `Dvorak International Extended` which has the features requested here and completed for Windows and Linux (code [here](http://arjenvankol.com/dvorak/dvorak_intl)) in the post [Dvorak international extended keyboard layout -
 Adding international support for the Dvorak Simplified Keyboard](http://arjenvankol.com/dvorak.php).

Fig. 1 Design of the Dvorak International Extended keyboard layout, 
Fig. 2 Searching `Dvorak` in Debian keyboard settings after the changes of Section *Installation attempt in Debian 8.7*, 
Fig. 3 Searching `extended` ...

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Installation attempt in Debian 8.7

I managed to complete the first two steps by the installation instructions, but failing to see the effect of addition of the keyboard layout there

1. [done] Copy this file to your `/etc/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` directory. You may need root privileges to do so.

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /etc/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
   sudo cp dvorak_int /etc/X11/xkb/symbols/pc/
   ```
2. Add the following line to `/etc/X11/xkb/rules/xfree86.lst`: `dvorak_intl Dvorak international extended`

   ```
    sudo touch /etc/X11/xkb/rules/xfree86.lst
    sudo echo `dvorak_intl Dvorak international extended` >> /etc/X11/xkb/rules/xfree86.lst
   ```
3. However, I cannot complete the third step

   ```
   // In order to make the keyboard layout available in GNOME,
   // you should also modify /etc/X11/xkb/rules/xfree86.xml
   // accordingly (this is an XML file and the format is mostly
   // self-explanatory).
   ```

   The command `apt search XF86Config` returns nothing because my system does not have the file `/etc/X11/xkb/rules/xfree86.xml`. 
   There is a typo in instructions (Thank You, clearkimura)! 
   Search the filename and edit it with the following, but still I am not sure what to fill there exactly - filename of the file or `dvorak-intl-extended` (my custom name)

   ```
   masi@masi:~$ dpkg --search xfree86.xml
   xkb-data: /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xfree86.xml

   masi@masi:~$ sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xfree86.xml
   ```

   Addition in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xfree86.xml`

   ```
       <variant>
         <configItem>
           <name>dvorak-intl-extended</name>
           <description>English (Dvorak, international extended with dead keys)</description>
         </configItem>
       </variant>
       <variant>
   ```

   I restart the system but unsuccessful outputs in Language Keyboard menu in Fig. 2 and Fig. 3.

   Maybe, something wrong with my permissions

   ```
    masi@masi:~$ sudo ls -la /etc/X11/xkb/symbols/pc/
    total 12
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 13 20:35 .
    drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 12 16:25 ..
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2989 May 12 16:26 dvorak_intl
   ```

   Directory permissions there should be fine

   ```
   masi@masi:~$ ls -la /etc/ | grep X11
   drwxr-xr-x  10 root root     4096 Sep  8  2016 X11
   masi@masi:~$ ls -la /etc/X11/ | grep xkb
   drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 May 12 16:25 xkb
   masi@masi:~$ ls -la /etc/X11/xkb/ | grep symbols
   drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 May 12 16:25 symbols
   masi@masi:~$ ls -la /etc/X11/xkb/symbols/ | grep pc
   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 13 20:35 pc
   ```

What should the permission be of the new keyboard layout?

OS: Debian 8.7

Comment: Um, `dpkg --search xfree86.xml` does return result in Ubuntu 14.04 and so do Debian 8. It is provided by `xkb-data: /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xfree86.xml`. The path was different though.

Comment: @clearkimura Thank you! Please, see my addition. I do not know what to exactly add to the file.

Comment: @clearkimura I restarted the system, but I could not see the new layout in the options. Please, see the edit.

Comment: I think something is off with the dated instruction in 2007. Don't most distro today run X.org instead of XFree86 server? In fact, I haven't seen any solution or tutorial that asks to edit `xfree86` files to setup a new keyboard layout.

Comment: @clearkimura I think `xfree86` is a part of X.org but not an expert here. 
 - - How can you do the corresponding change directly on X.org.

Comment: `xfree86` was replaced by `xorg` a number of releases ago. Maybe the instructions you found need an update to reflect this.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 After continuing my research on "how to setup new keyboard layout using xkb", I managed to install several layouts. Still testing whether it is persistent or not. I might post an answer soon.

Comment: @clearkimura Good! I wait for it.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Finally posted my answer; Didn't expect to be lengthy and several hours to test and write the answer. If there is any clarification, I will review this thread a day later.

Comment: `xfree86` rules are no longer used in modern XKB.  you'll want to modify `evdev`, `evdev.lst` and `evdev.xml` instead. (you'd modify the `base` templates if you're creating a patch per https://askubuntu.com/a/901356/669043).

Comment: @quixotic Can you please show how to do it?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355404/222377 for rule file details